# Javascript time difference

Tags: javascript, time

I am trying to simply calculate the time difference of 5:30:00 - 2:30:00. Obviously this should result in 3:00:00

However when I execute following code in console

```js
var a = new Date(0,0,0,5,30,0)
var b = new Date(0,0,0,2,30,0)
var c = new Date(a-b)
console.log(c.getHours() + ":" + c.getMinutes() + ":" + c.getSeconds())
```

The result is 4:00:00.

What is causing this problem? And how should I handle it?

[image: Weird]

Comment: Try convert to milliseconds before the "math operation".

Comment: Why not convert the times to seconds, do the arithmetic and convert back to h:m:s?

Comment: Use the `UTC` methods, ie `getUTCHours()`

Comment: Thats weird, my friend also got 3:00:00 could it possibly be a thing with time zone?

Comment: I get 22:0:0 as an output.

Comment: don't use a `Date` object - parse the string accordingly.

Comment: I got 20 for what its worth.

Comment: @Phil that does the trick

Comment: I get 1:0:0 in ouput (Opera and Firefox browser), possibly is a problem with the time zone.

Comment: @DanielA.White I don't get what you mean by parse the string?

Comment: You should bypass time zone and summer/winter hours effect which means you should use utc time. Or you can simply calculate it from subtraction result which is in milliseconds.

Comment: `Date` constructor is not suitable to represent/parse time spans.

Comment: @zerkms so what should i use instead?

Comment: Just convert `5:30:00` string to seconds, it's a trivial math. Then convert the other. Then subtract.

Comment: I got 6:0:0. Do not use dates for such calculations.

Comment: `'5:30:00'.split(':').reduce((acc, v) => acc * 60 + parseInt(v), 0)` <--- that

Comment: The output takes time zones into account. Anyone who got 4:00 is at UTC+1. Who got 6:00 is at UTC+3. The person with 22:00 is at UTC-5 etc.

Comment: What @zerkms said. Dates `a` and `b` will have the correct values, but when subtracting them from each other, you don't get a date, but a _time span_, for which the `Date` class is not suitable at all. You'll get the offset of your current timezone added to that `Date` as a consequence. FWIW, you *could* get the correct value using `console.log((c.getHours() - Math.floor(c.getTimezoneOffset() / 60)) + ":" + (c.getMinutes() - c.getTimezoneOffset() % 60) + ":" + c.getSeconds())` but ugh... please just don't, and use `a.getHours()-b.getHours()` and so instead.

Comment: @Siguza a.getHours()-b.getHours() wont work in case a = 2:20:00 and b =  00:30:00 eg

Comment: @Herocaine "`.getHours()` **and so**. With that I meant `.getMinutes()`, `.getSeconds()` and whatever else you wanna call on them. Just apply the `-` to each value individually, and not on the objects themselves.

Comment: @Siguza well in case of a = 2:20:00 and b = 00:30:00 I would get 2:-10:00 if I understand you correctly ...

Comment: @Herocaine There's also negative values to consider and whatnot, but I trust you know how to use modulo and get around that. :)

Answer (score 2):

`Date` constructor is not suitable to either represent or deal the time spans.

There are no built-in tools to handle time spans in JS, so you need to implement one yourself.

Thankfully the `time string -> seconds` conversion is trivial:

```
const timeToSec = time => time.split(':').reduce((acc, v) => acc * 60 + parseInt(v), 0);
```

Then you can deal with seconds:

```
const diffInSeconds = timeToSec('5:30:00') - timeToSec('2:30:00'); // 10800
```

The reverse transformation of `seconds -> time string` is also trivial (and tbh it's simple reversed of the `timeToSec` implementation) and I'm leaving it as a home work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why people get different results is timezone.

When you calculate *c* as the difference between two dates, you actually get a date relative to 01.01.1970. In this case, when you do:

```
console.log(c);
```

You get something like:

```
1970-01-01T03:00:00.000Z
```

This is in UTC Date format.

But now if you would display *c* in the local time zone:

```
console.log(c.toLocaleDateString()+ ' ' + c.toLocaleTimeString());
```

... then you get maybe this:

```
1-1-1970 04:00:00
```

If you then take the hours of that date with `getHours()`, you get them from the date/time as it is in your time zone, in your case you are on GMT+1, which means the outcome is 4.

To avoid this time zone conversion, use the UTC versions of the `getXXXX` functions, like `getUTCHours`. Note that some time zones have non-integer hour differences with UTC (with an half-hour part), so they would need to use `getUTCMinutes` as well.

Be aware that converting date differences to Date format will start to give wrong results when you cover larger spans, crossing 29 February, ...etc. Differences are best calculated by taking the date differences (in milliseconds) without conversion to Date. From there it is straightforward to calculate the number of seconds, minutes, ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to assume that your question is not merely about the difference between two numbers, but it is a real problem.
Then, the answer is: without specifying the day(s), the difference between two *hours* is meaningless, you must always specify which day(s) you are talking about.

For example Europe, Berlin:

> Sunday, 27 March 2016, 02:00:00 clocks were turned
>   forward 1 hour.

Like in your example, this would lead to pay someone 1 hour more than it had worked...

> Sunday, 30 October 2016, 03:00:00 clocks are turned backward 1 hour

..calculating the same interval Sunday, 30 October 2016 would do the opposite.

**Moreover**, be aware that daylight saving time has become standard in the U.S., Canada, and most European countries. However, most of the world doesn't even use it.

**Moreover**, during the past, starting day and ending day of saving time has been changed from year to year, and the starting hour has been also changed, i.e. you cannot assume always 2.00 at night - so reconstruct an interval without knowing this information would not lead to a correct result.

A possible solution to calculate correctly a duration, is always to store next the Local Date/Time also the UTC Date/Time and do the calculation keeping both in account, so you have **both the Timezone and the Daylight Saving Time Shift** to get back the exact start date/time and ending date/time.

If you don't have this information already stored, then you should retrieve them, for example, from a online Time Database.

Answer (score 0):

usage

```
node time_diff.js 5:30:00 2:30:00
```

will output: 03:00:00

code of time_diff.js:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
if (!process.argv[2] || !process.argv[3]) {
    console.log('usage: time_diff hh:mm:ss hh:mm:ss');
    process.exit(1);
}
const timeToSec     = (time) => time.split(':').reduce((acc, v) => acc * 60 + parseInt(v), 0);
const diffInSeconds = (time1, time2) => timeToSec(time2) - timeToSec(time1); 
const hhmmss = (secs) => {
    var minutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);
    secs = secs % 60;
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes = minutes % 60;
    return pad(hours) + ":" + pad(minutes) + ":" + pad(secs);
    function pad(num) {
        return ("0" + num).slice(-2);
    }
};
try {
    console.log(hhmmss(diffInSeconds(process.argv[3], process.argv[2])));
}
catch (err) {
    console.log('usage: time_diff hh:mm:ss hh:mm:ss');
    process.exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple plugin to get time differences.

https://github.com/gayanSandamal/good-time

import the goodTimeDiff method from good-time.js to your project

```
import {goodTimeDiff} from './scripts/good-time.js'
```

declare an object to give settings like below. let settings = {}

now assign time values to the declared object variable. ***time must be in standard format and must be a string! ***'from' is optional the default value will be the browser current time.

```
let settings = {
    'from': '2019-01-13T00:00:29.251Z',
    'to': '2018-09-22T17:15:29.251Z'
}
```

now calllback the method called goodTimeDiff() and pass the settings object variable as a parameter.

```
goodTimeDiff(settings)
```

Finally assign the method to any variable you want.

```
let lastCommentedTime = goodTimeDiff(timeSettings)
```

Answer (score -1):

`a - b` results in three hours, but in milliseconds. You just need to convert milliseconds to hours (which is  not `new Date(milliseconds)`).

try: `(a-b)/1000/60/60`

---

Formatted:

```
var a = new Date(0,0,0,5,30,0)
var b = new Date(0,0,0,2,30,0)
var diff = (a.getTime()-b.getTime())
var h = Math.floor(diff/1000/60/60)
var m = ('0' + Math.floor((diff/1000/60)%60) ).substr(-2)
var s = ('0' + Math.floor((diff/1000)%60) ).substr(-2)

console.log(h + ':' + m + ':' + s)
```

---

**EDIT**

For those who want to treat a **time span** as a **date**... just get the UTC date, which means Coordinated Universal Time. In other words, don't use timezone aware methods:

```
var a = new Date(0,0,0,5,30,0)
var b = new Date(0,0,0,2,30,0)
var c = new Date(a-b)
console.log(c.getUTCHours() + ":" + c.getUTCMinutes() + ":" + c.getUTCSeconds())
```

Be aware though, this will fall apart on edge cases...

Comment: Seriously, why the downvote? Everybody going on about dates and whatnot, when this is in fact a much simpler problem...

Comment: first method also seems to be faster - https://albertxing.com/stool/#0056d015576ed3f630516ca7dcf83029

Comment: I updated your answer to remove the comment you made in it about downvoters. This way I have something to upvote ;-)